# COVID time series

Tags: time-series

I was asked this question I took a couple semesters back, but the prof never posted the solution and I got it wrong. The question went as "Obtain a time series of the monthly COVID cases in the US since March 2020. Fit a time series to the data using a window of past values of 4. Forecast the next 3 months. Although we are in 2022, how would one go about solving this problem. The software we used was Maple, so I'm not sure posting this question here is best or not.